# Solve Mean-Variance Problem by Expected Return Maximization

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qclp

One period market with n securities with return R~ $N(\mu,\Sigma)$. An expected return on each security is $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$

Investor has 1 unit of wealth and invests into n assets, with weights $w_1,\dots,w_n$ so that the sum of the $w_i$=1.

To solve the mean-variance problem, given the expected return on this portfolio is $p$, and allow the short-sale.

The minimum variance portfolio problem can be solved by Lagrange Multiplier:
$$min\quad w^T\Sigma w$$
subject to:$$w_1+\dots+w_n=1$$ $$\mu_1w_1+\dots+\mu_nw_n=p$$
The Lagrangian is:
$$\mathcal{L}=w^T\Sigma w-\lambda_1(a^Tw-p)-\lambda_2(w^Te-1)$$
Where $e$ is the all-ones matrix and $a$ is $[\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_n]$. After first order conditions,$$w=\lambda_1\Sigma^{-1}\mu+\lambda_2\Sigma^{-1}e$$
So that
$$1=\lambda_1e^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu+\lambda_2e^T\Sigma^{-1}e$$
$$p=\lambda_1\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu+\lambda_2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}e$$

and in a matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} e^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu & e^T\Sigma^{-1}e \\\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu&\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}e \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 
1\\p\end{bmatrix}$$

and the solution for $w$ is:
$$w=\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma^{-1}\mu&\Sigma^{-1}e\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} e^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu & e^T\Sigma^{-1}e \\\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu&\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}e \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 
1\\p\end{bmatrix}$$

Follow this logic, if I want to solve the **maximum expected return mean-variance problem**, I have an objective function:
$$max\quad w^Ta$$
subject to:
$$w^T\Sigma w=\sigma^2,\quad where \ \sigma^2\text{is the given variance of the portfolio}$$
$$w^Te=1$$

**But when I applied equivalent Lagrange multiplier approach, I can't get the correct results which should be similar as the minimum variance context.** Is this because the quadratic programming cannot be used when we have non-linear constraints? And I hope to get a similar result so I can put it into the MatLab to do an empirical study project.

Comment: The solutions should be identical, could you share your steps? If you solve the problem numerically, phrase the constraint as $w^T \Sigma w \leq \sigma^2$ to make the problem convex.

Comment: Hi Lin, I don't think the solutions are identical. The minimum variance function is when you input an expected return on the portfolio, for example,$a$, the function will output the weights. But for maximum expected return function, your input will be a fixed variance ($\sigma^2$).

Comment: obviously, but you should get identical results if you put the optimal variance from the first problem as the target in the second problem